# A domino is a $2$ by $1$ rectangle. For what integers $m$ and $n$ can we cover an $m$ by $n$ rectangle with non-overlapping dominoes?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Question: A domino is a $2$ by $1$ rectangle. For what integers $m$ and $n$ can we cover an $m$ by $n$ rectangle with non-overlapping dominoes?

My approach: Let us divide the $m$ by $n$ rectangle into $mn$ unit squares. Observe that a domino covers exactly two adjacent unit squares at a time, irrespective of its orientation on the $m$ by $n$ rectangle. Let this property be called $P$.

Now clearly four cases are possible:

(1) $m$ is odd, $n$ is odd.

(2) $m$ is odd, $n$ is even.

(3) $m$ is even, $n$ is odd.

(4) $m$ is even, $n$ is even.

Claim: We can cover the rectangle using the domino in each of the cases (2), (3) and (4), but not (1).

Proof: Take any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now let $m=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We will induct on $k$.

Base Case ($k=1$): Therefore, in this case we have a $2\times n$ rectangle. Observe that we can certainly cover such a rectangle using exactly $n$ dominoes placed horizontally.

Hypothesis: Let us assume that we can cover up a $m\times n$ rectangle where $m=2k'$ for some $k=k'\in\mathbb{N}$.

Induction: Now we have a $(2k'+2)\times n$ rectangle. Now already by our hypothesis we have the $m\times n$ part completely covered up with dominoes. Therefore, the question reduces to if we can cover up a $2\times n$ rectangle or not, and that we can surely do by our base case.

This completes the induction. Thus we can cover up any $m\times n$ rectangle where $m$ is any even natural number and $n$ is any natural number. Therefore, we are done with cases (3) and (4).

Now observe that, if we can cover up a $m\times n$ rectangle, then we can surely cover up a $n\times m$ rectangle. This clearly implies that, since we have shown that a covering is possible in (3), therefore we are sure that a covering should be possible for (2).

Now let us assume that a covering is possible for (1). Now by property $P$ we must have $mn$ to be an even number, but in this case $mn$ is odd, which is a clear contradiction. Thus a covering is not possible for (1).

Thus a covering is possible only for cases (2), (3) and (4). Thus in general we can conclude that at least one of $m,n$ should be even for a covering to be possible.

Can someone check if this solution is correct or not?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your argument but it seems needlessly verbose. If $n$ is even, a $1\times n$ rectangle ($1$ unit high, $n$ units wide) can be covered with $n/2$ dominoes placed horizontally. If $n$ is even and $m\gt1$, an $m\times n$ rectangle is a stack of $m$ $1\times n$ rectangles, so it too can be covered with dominoes. This takes care of all cases with $n$ even. A similar argument works if $m$ is even. If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then it's impossible, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

(2)-(4) are obvious because it's obvious even for the rectangle $1\times n$, where $n$ is even.